# Layout of a Class

Tags: c#

Is there a definite recommended layout to Classes in C#?

Here is an example with layout questions ...

```
 public class DinnerParty {

      //>>>>should the const fields that are initiallised with a value be at the top?
    private const int CostOfFoodPerPerson = 25;

      //>>>>should the constructor always be placed near the top of the class?
    public DinnerParty(int numberOfPeople, bool Health, bool fancyDecorations) {
        NumberOfPeople = numberOfPeople;
        this.fancyDecorations = fancyDecorations;
        Health = healthyOption;
        CalculateCostOfDecorations(fancyDecorations);
    }

      //>>>>backing private fields should always precede properties that use them?
    private int numberOfPeople;
    public int NumberOfPeople {
        get {
            return numberOfPeople;
        } 
        set {
            CalculateCostOfDecorations(fancyDecorations);
            numberOfPeople = value;
        }
    }

      //>>>>where do these fields go?
    private bool fancyDecorations;
    public decimal costOfBeveragePerPerson;

    private bool healthyOption;
    public bool HealthyOption{
        set {
            value =  healthyOption;
            if (healthyOption) {
                costOfBeveragePerPerson = 5.0M;
            } else {
                costOfBeveragePerPerson = 20.0M;
            }
        }
    }

     //>>>>should methods be placed after the constructor and all properties?
    public decimal costOfDecorations = 0;
    void CalculateCostOfDecorations(bool fancy) {
        if (fancy) {
            costOfDecorations = (numberOfPeople * 15.0M) + 50.0M;
        } else {
            costOfDecorations = (numberOfPeople * 7.50M) + 30.0M;
        }
    }

    public decimal CalculateCost(bool xfancy, bool xhealthyOption) {
        decimal totalCost = (numberOfPeople * (CostOfFoodPerPerson + costOfBeveragePerPerson)) + costOfDecorations;
        if (xhealthyOption) {
            return totalCost * 0.95M;
        } else {
            return totalCost;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like this may get closed; I suspect for being not specific enough - anyone got any tips for edits to the question to make it more acceptable? (I feel possible answers to the question are useful)

Comment: It falls into a semi-code-review area that isn't really covered by SO, Code Review, or Programmers. I don't think it makes a good question, but it might make an OK-ish community wiki.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth how do I switch it to community wiki?

Comment: Actually, please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth ok - I'll mark one of the posts as the answer and then try to mark it as community wiki

Comment: According to the link there should be a box I tick to make it community wiki... can't find it; maybe I've not got enought re to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StyleCop has these rules:

- Within a class, struct, or interface, elements must be positioned in the following order:

  - Constant Fields
  - Fields
  - Constructors
  - Finalizers (Destructors)
  - Delegates
  - Events
  - Enums
  - Interfaces
  - Properties
  - Indexers
  - Methods
  - Structs
  - Classes
- Elements of the same type must be positioned in the following order by access level:

  - public
  - internal
  - protected internal
  - protected
  - private
- All static elements must be placed above all instance elements of the same type.

See [the documentation](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/Ordering%20Rules.html) for details.

Comment: Of course, these rules are optional ;-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Yes, of course. But they are *one* accepted standard in the .NET world.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Using ReSharpers Clean Code facility together with the StyleCop plugin and a matching configuration lets you change a complete codebase to adhere to the rules in a matter of minutes.

Comment: The intent was to highlight to passers-by that your answer is not a "definite recommended way", it is just one opinion that happens to be commonly used as it has tool support.

Comment: Of course, but it makes merging and history a little painful. I simply find it doesn't offer any value. I have not seen an improvement in my productivity because a file was written in a certain order. For me, it is purely aesthetics.

Comment: I was originally going to say that my point was that your answer was just *one* opinion, but I removed that and left my comment about personally not using it. In hindsight, on it's own it is a little pointless. I'll remove it.

Comment: it's going to help me personally if I get into the habit of setting all my classes out the same - in the future then when looking back on old classes I will be able to find the section I want more easily. + spotting problems in the patterns might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I tend towards:

- Events
- Fields (including constants)
- Properties (including indexers and auto-properties)
- Constructors
- Public / protected / internal / private methods.
- Nested Types

That said, I try to respect the order of the file as it stands, as needlessly moving stuff around causes **merge pains**.

I'm not sure if there is a definitive way of writing the class content; even if there was I'd take it with a pinch of salt, at the end of the day this would also just be someone's opinion. Be consistent and just try to keep the code neat (I personally hate it when the code file is littered with random whitespace from pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> too many times).

<sub>Another important factor on helping merges remain palatable is to have consistent settings on code formatting (in-line versus new-line brackets, brackets around single line if statements, etc).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do...

- variable declarations
- Methods
- Properties
  ...in that order.

Other people have their own preferences. The only hard rule that I can think of is to **be consistent** - regardless of your preferences, if you are clear & predictable, it makes it far easier for the next guy to pick up.